# spring-boot jackson single object as array

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am having an issue with resolving a single object as an array I have used the following property

```
# JACKSON (JacksonProperties).
spring.jackson.deserialization.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY=true
```

In addition to the above I have configured a rest template as follows:

```
@Test
    public void testSingleObject() {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
         ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter convertor = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
        convertor.setObjectMapper(mapper);
        mapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY);
        restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(convertor);
        MockRestServiceServer mockServer = MockRestServiceServer.createServer(restTemplate);
        mockServer.expect(requestTo("/test/1")).andExpect(method(HttpMethod.GET))
                .andRespond(withSuccess("{\"size\":\"1\",\"Value\":{\"@id\": \"1\",\"description\":\"Some Text\"}}", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
       // JsonNode jsonNode = restTemplate.getForObject("/test/{id}", JsonNode.class, 1);
        mycalss value = restTemplate.getForObject("/test/{id}", myclass.class, 1);
        System.out.print(value.toString());
    }
```

I am using spring-boot 1.3.2, the error I get is

```
Could not read document: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token
```

Ps: If I try this without rest template it works as expected

```
@Test
    public void testSingleObject3() throws IOException {
        final String json = "{\"size\":\"1\",\"Value\":{\"@id\": \"1\",\"description\":\"Some Text\"}}";

        final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
                .enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY);
        myclass value = mapper.readValue(json,
                new TypeReference<myclass>() {
        });
        System.out.println(value.toString());
    }
```

my class is defined a follows :

```
//@JsonFormat(with = JsonFormat.Feature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY)
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class myclass {
@JsonProperty("size")
private String Size;
@JsonProperty("value")
private List<mysubclass> mysubclass;
@JsonIgnore
private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>(); 
//... setters and getters
```

mysubclass is defined as follows:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
"id",
"description"
})
public class mysubclass {

@JsonProperty("@id")
private String Id;
@JsonProperty("description")
private String description;
@JsonIgnore
private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
```

Regards

Comment: Can you also provide the code for `myclass`?

Comment: Your question helped answer one I had myself. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do

```
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(converter);
```

you're actually adding a second jackson converter to the `RestTemplate`'s list of converters.

When you run the code, the first one (which was added by default by the `RestTemplate` constructor) is being used so it doesn't matter that you've configured the second one.

If you change that piece of code to

```
restTemplate.setMessageConverters(Collections.singletonList(converter));
```

the default converters will be discarded and only the one you've configured will be used.